# Need to update href in custom.js with IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to customize a custom.js file in a Wordpress installation from a previous developer. The current file has this block of code that opens a modal allowing the user to select "Admin Site" which will direct that user to the appropriate site for signing in.

```
    jQuery('body').on('click','#btn-signin-popup-partners',function(e){
        var host = window.location.host
        e.preventDefault();
        body='<div class="padding-30">';
        body+='<p class="text-center">Are you a current RDS Partner? Click on the button below to access your account.</p>';
        body+='<a href="https://admin.xyz.com/Account/Login" type="button" class="btn btn-success full-width btn-admin-site">Admin Site</a>';
        body+='</div>';
        modal_show(body);
    });
```

I need to replace the href with a new href based on the value of 'host'.

I have tried a couple of solutions with varying degrees of success/failure.

First I updated the code with this:

```
    jQuery('body').on('click','#btn-signin-popup-partners',function(e){
        var host = window.location.host
        e.preventDefault();
        body='<div class="padding-30">';
        body+='<p class="text-center">Are you a current RDS Partner? Click on the button below to access your account.</p>';
        if (host === "demopartners.xyz.com") {
          "body+='<a href="https://demoadmin.xyz.com/Account/Login" type="button" class="btn btn-success full-width btn-admin-site">Admin Site</a>';";
        } else {
          "body+='<a href="https://admin.xyz.com/Account/Login" type="button" class="btn btn-success full-width btn-admin-site">Admin Site</a>';";
        }
        body+='</div>';
        modal_show(body);
    });
```

That disabled the "Sign In" button that opened the Modal. So I updated my if statement and removed the opening/closing quotes.

```
    jQuery('body').on('click','#btn-signin-popup-partners',function(e){
        var host = window.location.host
        e.preventDefault();
        body='<div class="padding-30">';
        body+='<p class="text-center">Are you a current RDS Partner? Click on the button below to access your account.</p>';
        if (host === "demopartners.xyz.com") {
          body+='<a href="https://demoadmin.xyz.com/Account/Login" type="button" class="btn btn-success full-width btn-admin-site">Admin Site</a>';
        } else {
          body+='<a href="https://admin.xyz.com/Account/Login" type="button" class="btn btn-success full-width btn-admin-site">Admin Site</a>';
        }
        body+='</div>';
        modal_show(body);
    });
```

That "works" but I get a lot of errors in the browser console.

The only thing I really need is to update the href, but not knowing a good solution for that I thought I could just replace that entire line of code with an IF statement based on the 'host' variable. Unfortunately everything I have tried has failed.

Comment: using your last code, the only error that I got was because it couldn't find 'modal_show'. Otherwise there were no errors.

Comment: imvain2 - let me recheck my custom.js file to be sure i haven't introduced an error somewhere else.

Comment: ok i must have made an error somewhere in this file that i didn't realize. i had to restore a clean copy of the file from a backup and then make this edit. after that everything is working fine.